# MS Word Characters: Database export then re-import causes ? marks

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

I know this question has been asked in many forms before but I could not find an answer to my specific question.

**THE SCENARIO**

Database Mysql, West European - Latin 1

Exported using sequel pro to sql file

Reimported the exact same file and had quotes, apostrophes, em dash, en dash, TM, Reg characters turn to question marks.

I fixed these by opening the sql file in vim and replacing the <94>, <95>, ect. hex codes with their correct counterpart.

Reference:
:%s/<93>/\'/g

[Source](http://aditya.sublucid.com/2008/01/18/replacing-those-pesky-smart-quotes-in-vim/)

**MY QUESTION**

How can I prevent this from happening in the future? My guess is that these characters are being pasted in from a **word doc** in the admin part of the website but I don't understand why it re-imports incorrectly. For now, I have replaced all the characters and everything is close to normal. Should I convert the table to utf8? I do have several translations of the site in the DB.

**NOTES**

I have exported this database several times before and never had this problem. I have exported it to a staging server (which is the same server as the live server, just a different host) and a local server. Any ideas of why this might happen all of a sudden?

I have looked into a lot of issues like double character encoding and wrong encoding formats but I think this situation is different. I also tried several of those solutions and they did not work.

**Similar Questions**

[Special characters get lost in MySQL export/import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185324/special-characters-get-lost-in-mysql-export-import)

Comment: every single step of the data travels should be encoded in utf-8. Maybe this post could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432833/1291428 check the exported file with ultra edit or similar and save it as utf-8 no bom

Comment: Even if the database is latin 1? Additionally, I think I tried to import as ut8f but sequel pro could not read the file as ut8f.

Comment: that's a severe issue. You can change your database encoding, the latin-1 character gruop is included into utf-8