# Moving from mysql 3.3 to mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql

I need to move my website with a mysql database on an old server with MySQL 3.23 to a new server with mysql 5.5.20

I have made a mysqldump with gzip and uploaded it to the new server. With gunzip file.sql.gz | mysql -uusername -ppasword dbname I tried to get it working. But I got an error. The error is

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-----
>
> CREATE TABLE lite_' at line 1

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For this specific error, remove the -- comment lines in your sql.
You can use any of the following:

```
sed -i '/^--/d' dumpfile.sql
awk '!/^--/' dumpfile.sql > filteredfile.sql
grep -v '^--' dumpfile.sql > filteredfile.sql
```

You might also ran into type errors for myisam.

[mysql error 'TYPE=MyISAM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471075/mysql-error-type-myisam)

Watch out for your type encodings.
you could remove all non-ASCII characters from your file

```
perl -plne 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' dumpfile.sql
```

[Special characters get lost in MySQL export/import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185324/special-characters-get-lost-in-mysql-export-import)

other notes on 3 to 5 conversion.

http://hisdeedsaredust.com/2009/02/mysql-version-3-to-version-5/

my other notes on mysql are available here:

http://dave.thehorners.com/tech-talk/random-tech/325-mysql

**IMHO, mysqlimport should have been written to support output from prior versions.**